# Trying to setBackgroundColor based off of a keyword in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to highlight a row in a table based off of the relevant keyword. However, my attempts at setting the background color of my range of cells have not yielded any colors. I used loggers inside the if/else statement and they all worked, so I think I'm doing `setBackgroundColor` wrong somehow.

```
function statusHighlighter(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  sheetValues.forEach(function(row, index) {
    var acctStatus = row[7];
    var highlightRange = sheetName.getRange(index+1, 1, 1, sheetName.getLastColumn());

    if(acctStatus === "Kept"){
      highlightRange.setBackgroundColor('##fffec4');
      Logger.log(acctStatus + " " + index);
    } else if(acctStatus === "Suspended"){
      highlightRange.setBackground('##cf4a4a');
    } else if(acctStatus === "Deleted"){
      highlightRange.setBackground('##6c75ad');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation / Issues:

There is one issue in your code and a couple of optimizations that I would like to suggest.

- The hex color codes must contain only **one** `#` but you are using two `##`.
- You are **iteratively** using [setBackground](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) but instead you can create an array with colors inside the `forEach` loop and then use [setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor) to set the colors in one go. Have a look at [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to see why.
- Since you have a particular column of interest, it makes sense to consider only **one** column instead of the full `dataRange`. In the following script, `acctStatusVals` considers only column `8`. I choose `8` because in your code you use the array index for `7` which is equivalent for column `8`. Be careful on that. In my code, `8` means column `H`. Adjust this to your needs. To convert the 2D array into 1D since we are using a single column, you can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- I use the following expression: `Array(lastCol).fill('#6c75ad')` to create an array of `lastCol` number of elements ([last column with content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)) and [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it with the same value, because the goal is to color the full row with the same color value.

### Optimized Solution:

Be careful with the active sheet. Make sure you select the right sheet before you run this code. I would advice you to use `ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');` but I leave it as a comment since this step is optional.

```
function statusHighlighter(){ 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet();
//  const sheetName = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to the name of your sheet
  const lastRow = sheetName.getLastRow();
  const lastCol = sheetName.getLastColumn();
  const acctStatusVals = sheetName.getRange(1,8,lastRow).getValues().flat();
  const colors = [];
  acctStatusVals.forEach(acctStatus=>{
   if(acctStatus === "Kept"){
      colors.push(Array(lastCol).fill('#fffec4'));
    } else if(acctStatus === "Suspended"){
      colors.push(Array(lastCol).fill('#cf4a4a'));
    } else if(acctStatus === "Deleted"){
      colors.push(Array(lastCol).fill('#6c75ad'));
    }                   
  });
  sheetName.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

**Sheet used for the above script:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was very helpful to see best practices in action for coding. The only change I had to make was tweaking lastRow to sheetName.getLastRow() - 1 and nudging up the sheetName.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastCol) to adjust for a header row. Thank you again for the help!